# Trying to install PIL but pip install PIL failed

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to install pil for editing photos via python
I used:

```
pip install pil
```

but it doesn't found anything ...
What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install pil you need to make:

```
pip install pillow
```

than you can import pil ...